# Which file will be loaded first in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working with cakephp , i need some clarification regarding initiating. 
which file will be loaded first in cakephp whether index.php or bootstrap file

Comment: I dont know why that question was upvoted. You could have easily found that out yourself. Simply but echo or die() statements in your two files and see what happens..

Comment: @-mark. yes you are correct , but there is a reason behind everything you know , i'm expecting not only the single word answer but the explanation to understand why and how and which..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of Ganesh is not really correct. It does not redirect and it does not load AppController as third file, nor does it load it ever directly.

First you should always configure your site to be accessed from the app/webroot folder NOT the index.php in the level above, because if you do that you expose the whole app structure to the public web as well.

When app/webroot/index.php is accessed CakePHP sets a bunch of constants like the CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH, WWW_ROOT and a few others, the best is to have a look at this file.

Then it will include the bootstrap.php file.

At the end of this file you'll see that not AppController but the Dispatcher is called first and the Request/Response classes are passed to it.

```
$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(
    new CakeRequest(),
    new CakeResponse()
);
```

[See Dispatcher::dispatch().](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Dispatcher.html#120)

Then, still no controller is loaded. It first fires events and by this dispatcher filters which can interrupt the request and already send data back to the client. That's how the AssetDispatcher works for example. Again, still no controller here.

If the filters passed then the dispatcher will call the controller that matches the requested url, not AppController, if you called /users/index it will instantiate the UsersController and call its index() method. See [Dispatcher::_loadController()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Dispatcher.html#244).

All your Controllers should extend AppController but AppController actually never gets called directly.

Comment: so ,  1. is index.php ( from project root) the first file be loaded ? 2. after that bootstrap , and not controller . is it correct??

Comment: What is project root for you? Like I said, you should configure your site so that the public entry point is app/webroot/index.php. The other index files point to that one but don't contain anything else. If you want to get an understanding how Cake loads up just go through the code of the files.

Comment: my project root is cakephp/

Answer (score -1):

When a cakephp application is accessed first it will load the index.php from there it redirects to bootstrap.php and then AppController.php.

Comment: thanks, but i have another doubt, there are many index.php files which file will be accessed?

Comment: index.php present in the root folder of your project.

Comment: Say cakephp is my project, contains app,lib,etc., cakephp/index.php this file will be loaded.

Comment: @S.Vivek you should always configure your site to be accessed from the *webroot* folder NOT the index.php in the level above, because if you do that you expose the whole app structure to the public web as well.